# How to swipe recycler view for only half of the screen height using espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a recycler view with different item views.
I need to test several of these  using espresso but I need to swipe the recycler in order for these item views to be visible.

How do I use espresso to swipe up but only for half of the screen or a custom amount of pixels? What are your suggestions?

I have tried using `ViewActions.swipeUp()` but it swipes all the way down.

Comment: use actionOnItem
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions#actiononitem